# Having lots of trouble with React and Redux setup and props

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-props

I'm building a Dashboard style app that would show data service outages. The backend is Rails 6 and I'm using React/Redux in the frontend (within Rails). I'm having lots of trouble (due to my greenness in Redux) with getting the data into the front end and mapping state to props. Would love for someone to look at my app and see where I'm going wrong. It seems like I'm also having issues with Lexical behaviour as well.

Here is the top of the app:

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom'
import Dashboard from './Dashboard';
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux'; // we get our store from redux library and we need middleware to wire up Thunk
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';

import reducers from './reducers/rootReducer'; 
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";

const storeEnhancers = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;

const store = createStore(reducers, storeEnhancers(applyMiddleware(thunk)));

// this is how you hook up
store.subscribe(() => {
    console.log('the new state is', store.getState()); 
    console.log('----------');
});



    render(
        <Provider store={store}>
        <Dashboard />
        </Provider>,
        document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('div')),
    )
```

This is the top visible component `Dashboard.js`

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import RecurringOutagesContainer from "./containers/RecurringOutagesContainer";
import FutureOutagesContainer from "./containers/FutureOutagesContainer";
import CurrentOutagesContainer from "./containers/CurrentOutagesContainer";
import CreateModalComponent from "./components/CreateModalComponent";
import { Container, Row, Col, Image } from "react-bootstrap";
import { getFutureOutages } from "./actions/fetchFutureOutagesAction";
import { getRecurringOutages } from "./actions/fetchRecurringOutagesAction";
import { getServices } from "./actions/fetchServicesAction";
import { connect } from 'react-redux'; 


class Dashboard extends Component {
  state = {
    services: [],
    outages: [], 
    showModal: false
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.getFutureOutages()
    this.props.getRecurringOutages()
    this.props.getServices()
  }


  render() {
    console.log(this.props)
    return (
      <div>
        <Container>
          <Row>
            <Col sm={1}>
              <img
                src={require("./public/logo-2-dashboard.png")}
                alt="logo"
                id="logo"
              ></img>
            </Col>
            <Col md={8}></Col>
          </Row>
        </Container>
        <div className="container">
          <div className="d-flex justify-content-md-end bd-highlight">

          </div>
        </div>
        <div className="d-flex justify-content-center bd-highlight dashboard">
          <div className="d-flex justify-content-start bd-highlight">
            <div className="d-fliex pastOutages">
              <h4>Past Outages</h4>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="d-flex justify-content-center bd-highlight">
            <div className="d-fliex currentOutages">
              <h4>Current Outages</h4>
              <div className="container">
                <div className="col-12">
                  <CurrentOutagesContainer currentOutages={this.props.services} />
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className="d-flex align-items-center flex-column bd-highlight">
            <div className="d-fliex justify-content-center">
              <h4>Future Outages</h4>
              <div className="container" id="futureOutages">
                <div className="col-12">
                  <FutureOutagesContainer futureOutages={this.props.futureOutages} />
                </div>
              </div>

              <h4>Recurring Outages</h4>
              <div className="container" id="recurringOutages">
                <div className="col-12">
                  <RecurringOutagesContainer recurringOutages={this.props.recurringOutages} />
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    futureOutages: state.futureOutages,
    recurringOutages: state.recurringOutages, 
    services: state.services
  }
};


const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return {
    getFutureOutages: () => dispatch(getFutureOutages()),
    getRecurringOutages: () => dispatch(getRecurringOutages()),
    getServices: () => dispatch(getServices())
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Dashboard); // this connects Dashboard to store
```

Here is one example of an `action` file:

```
\\ fetchFutureOutagesAction.js 

import axios from 'axios'; 

export const getFutureOutages = () => dispatch => {
    axios.get("/future_outages")
    .then(res => {
       const futureOutages = res.data; 
       dispatch({ type: 'FUTURE_OUTAGES', payload: futureOutages });
    })
       .catch(res => console.log(res.errors)); 
};
```

I have a rootReducer like so:

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux'; 
import { futureOutagesReducer } from './futureOutagesReducer';
import { recurringOutagesReducer } from './recurringOutagesReducer';
import { servicesReducer } from './servicesReducer';
export default combineReducers({
    futureOutages: futureOutagesReducer, 
    recurringOutages: recurringOutagesReducer,
    services: servicesReducer
});
```

and here is an example of a `reducer` file:

```
const initialState = {
    futureOutages: []
}

export const futureOutagesReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'FUTURE_OUTAGES':
            return { futureOutages: [...state.futureOutages, action.payload] };
        default: 
            return state;
    }
}
```

The errors are occuring in the `container` files that I pass props down to from `Dashboard.jsx':

```
import React from "react";
import FutureOutagesComponent from "../components/FutureOutagesComponent"

const FutureOutagesContainer = props => {

   return (
    <div>
         {props.futureOutages && props.futureOutages.map((futureOutage, idx) => (
           <FutureOutagesComponent key={idx} futureOutage={futureOutage} />
         ))
         }
    </div>
  )

};

export default FutureOutagesContainer;
```

When I start `./bin/webpack-dev-server.js`, here is a snapshot of errors in console I'm getting:

[image]

So clearly the props are not being passed down correctly. Can someone give me some pointers on implementing this better? I had everything working with just a React app but really want to have more flexibility accessing `state` through out the app.

Comment: Please post text, not images of text.

Comment: Is it ok for this post or do I need to edit?

Answer (score 1):

Based on your reducer, I think you will need to access future outages like this.

```
const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    futureOutages: state.futureOutages.futureOutages
  }
};
```

The name of your reducer is `futureOutages` and it also has a property by the same name whose value is an array.

```
export default combineReducers({
  // state.futureOutages
  futureOutages: futureOutagesReducer,
  ...
})
```

Accessing `state.futureOutages` will give you an object which is the full piece of state for that reducer from the Refux store. But you want a specific property. Because it's an object and not array, `Array.prototype.map` is not a func. HTH.

Comment: Yep.  The extra level of nesting in the reducer is unnecessary - the reducer state could just be the array by itself.

Comment: Ok great. So if I did just `return  [...state.futureOutages, action.payload ] `, it seems like I wouldn't have to worry about the awkward Object naming.

Comment: Now I'm running into an issue where the component props from `mapStateToProps` creates a nested array. Looks like `futureOutages: [[...]]`